# How do I query posts for a custom post type with a specific custom taxonomy created in Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm trying to query posts as part of a page template from a custom post type (Places) in a specific taxonomy (Genres > Dine) but it's showing up blank after the general page content. Below is my code and I'm researching to see what I'm doing wrong but no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                        
<hr>

<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'places',
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genres',
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => 'dine'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php
   while($query->have_posts()) :
      $query->the_post();
?>
<div class="row align-items-center" id="place">
    <div class="col-md-3" data-aos="fade-up">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 left" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="250">
        <div class="info">
            <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_field('description'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="500">
        <div class="address">
            <?php the_field('physical_address'); ?>
        </div>
        <b><?php the_field('phone'); ?> <br></b>
        <p><a href="<?php the_field('website'); ?>" target="_blank">Website</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Comment: Can't see why that should not work, at a quick glance. Can you show us how the taxonomy for the custom post type was set up during its registration?

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for responding. Here is a link to the general settings in ACF for that taxonomy - https://ibb.co/T1w2DPc